Is $\mbox{row}_i(A) \cup \mbox{col}_j(A)$ for a matrix $A$ a thing?
In working on a research problem in order theory, I have encountered a symmetric rank-1 matrix that can be expressed as
$$
A = 30 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\\\ 1/5 \\\\ 1/2 \\\\ 1/6 \\\\ 1/15 \\\\ 1/30
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\\\ 1/5 \\\\ 1/2 \\\\ 1/6 \\\\ 1/15 \\\\ 1/30
\end{pmatrix}^\mbox{T} .
$$
For reasons specific to my problem, I'm interested in the function $f$ that maps each $a_{ij}$ to the union of $\mbox{row}_i(A)$ and $\mbox{col}_j(A)$ (obviously taken as the sets of their respective entries).
Is this kind of function already a thing? If so, what's it called, and what are its known properties? I'd really like to be able to reason about the members of $f(a_{ij})$ for arbitrary $i$ and $j$. And just to be clear, the $i$'s and $j$'s are of no interest beyond their use as indices. What I'm interested in is $A$'s entries themselves, and how each one's value may relate to its image under $f$.
Of course, it wouldn't be a particularly onerous job to simply brute-force it and fish out the 36 sets by inspection---I know that for this particular matrix $A$, $|\{a_{ij}:1\leq i,j \leq 6\}| = 19$---but the extensional values of the $f(a_{ij})$'s aren't as illuminating as I'd like. And my gut tells me that there's something interesting lurking in this set-valued function. Ideally, I'd like to be able to construct $f(a_{ij})$ directly from $a_{ij}$ and without looking things up in $A$. I do have a way to acquire $i$ and $j$ from the value of $a_{ij}$, though it's more an algorithm than a formula.

So you're regarding a vector as a set?

Yes, @Randall, by the simple mapping $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_6) \mapsto \cup_{i=1}^6 {x_i}$. (Or $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_6)^{\mathrm T}$, as the case may be.)

You can make all kinds of functions but unless they have some interesting properties it's unlikely they'll be studied. I don't see how the vector axioms are of any use to such a function so it begs the question why you're using vectors for this.

@CyclotomicField, the data is intrinsically 2-dimensional, so it cries out to be expressed in a $6\times 6$ array. As soon as I did that it became clear that if one views the array as a matrix, then it's symmetric and has rank 1. And based on the semantics from my application, the 2-D layout also has something of the feeling of graphs' adjacency matrices.  But it's not as though I have found occasion for anything like computing dot products or computing powers of $A$.
